# Macro help on "clicking" button with excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have internal URLs for my company where we were able to run macros daily with the `ie.Document.getElementsByName("submit")(0).Select` command.  This is no longer working with Excel, which I assume is part of some recent MS or specifically Excel updates.

Basically it's just a command to click a button when the target URL is loaded.  I'm stumped on this one.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You've provided no url not any html source but typically I just identify the form and form.submit.

Comment: Check if the element name is the same as it was. What is the error message?